# Scanning through bytes in a process

Tags: c++, function, byte, call

I am currently developing a program and the idea involves scanning through all bytes in a process (the process the dll is injected into) and if a function is found at the byte, returning information and continuing the scan.

My only question is - what's the most effecient way to scan through all bytes in a process (current process) and checking if the bytes scanned are a function?

Comment: So... `I'm writing a program, and my only question is how to write the program.` Am I missing something?

Comment: No, the program is a lot more involved than that - that's the only part i'm stuck on. Scanning through the bytes is relatively simple (just looking at any old FindPattern code), but i'm not sure how to scan through ALL the bytes and check if the bytes scanned are actually a function. I don't need spoonfed - just some advice or tips.

Comment: How can you tell if the byte belongs to a function?  to the start of a function?  Is the code Big Endian?  Little Endian?

Comment: "are a function" meaning "starts with some suitable instruction and ends with some other instruction", or are you looking for a particular function? [Removed your `scanning` tag, as this question is not about reading images with a scanner]

Comment: Sorry mat. Basically, the idea is to "hook" all functions in a process and print to a log displaying calls. It's a tool i've been developing for monitoring function calls in a program. So the idea was to write a function that hooks the function at the bytes you supply as an argument - and to scan through all bytes and hook any bytes that turn out as a "valid" (non NULL?) function.

Comment: Nel,  you're going to need the map file of the process.  You are also going to need to know the byte-code of the instructions that call functions.  This is all processor dependent, which you still haven't provided.

Comment: @thomas - intel 4770k, windows 7 64bit

Comment: And watch out for "things that look like a call but isn't" (or "looks like beginning of functon". Like was suggested, a map-file or debug information would be hugely helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, that's a pretty hopeless goal. At least for a first attempt, I'd hook exported functions (based on the mention of DLL and such, I'm assuming this is on Windows).

If you want to scan for more functions that aren't exported, the next step would probably be to disassemble the code and look for `Call` instructions, then save the target addresses for each of them as being the entry point of a function.

Realistically, that's unlikely to do a whole lot of good though--being able to log functions without knowing that they are/do is likely to generate a lot of output, but little real information.

Comment: Ahh, this is the kind of answer i was looking for. I imagine you can use ollydbg's, disasm.c/.h lib to dynamically check for call instructions? I would like to log function calls for more than just the exported funcs.

Comment: @SkylerNelson: Yes, that would be one good possibility for doing the disassembly.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient method to scan memory for a byte is to use any specialized processor instructions.

Haul the data into the processor's data cache, then scan it.

If you can, fetch in byte sizes that fit into your processor's word size.  For example, an ARM7TDMI processor has 32-bit word size, which means it can fetch 4 bytes at a time.  So the processor is most efficient fetching in multiple of four bytes.

For more detailed information, we need more detailed information about your platform, including OS and processor.

Comment: processor intel 4770k, windows 7 64bit